# How can I view the contents of an .srt file on my Android?

Tags: files

OS: 4.1.1
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3

I have a French .srt file that I want to view and edit the contents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `.srt` looks more like a subtitles file for subtitling films, a plain text file, with time frame where spoken language is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open a text file of any extension in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53707/how-do-i-open-a-text-file-of-any-extension-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

.srt is just text. So, I'm sure you can edit it using any text editor like [Jota+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota.plus).

Give it a try, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried it yet! Wanted to look into the price.  :-)

Comment: @verve The free version is good enough. :)

Comment: Is there a word counter on it?

Comment: @verve Doesn't look like it has one

Answer (score 1):

> With Subtitle Editor Free you can edit your subtitles in your mobile
>   phone. Application support several different encodings and you can
>   edit time, text, re-sync subtitles and app has a lot of other
>   functions. Try this app!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixedapps.subtitlescreator

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension from `.srt` to `.txt`, then any word editor will work.
I use ES file explorer's editor.

When finished, change the extension back to `filename.srt`. It works fine for me.