# How do I open a text file of any extension in Android?

Tags: dropbox, text-editor

I have several types of file on my Google Drive and on my SD card (.C, .ASM, .H, .INC, .LOG) which are all just text files. But I just can't view them on my Android phone because it says that there are no programs assigned to that file type. Dropbox would do fine if I could just assign it to open these extensions. So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to assign any extension I want to Dropbox?
2. Is there a text viewer that will let me do that?

I tried so many, but none seem to do it. Only this HEX editor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tuba.tools seem to do it, but it won't allow me to view as a text file. Only in a split HEX/TEXT screen.

Comment: Jave you tried [920 Text Editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/920-Text-Editor/com.jecelyin.editor) or [DroidEdit](http://www.appbrain.com/app/DroidEdit-free-code-editor/com.aor.droidedit)? They at least offer syntax highlighting for multiple programmin languages. I just don't know whether they also associate with their repective file extensions/mime types.

Comment: WOW the 920 Text Editor is really nice, it opens .ASM as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

A programming editor might solve your issue. Take a look at e.g. [920 Text Editor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/920-Text-Editor/com.jecelyin.editor) or [DroidEdit](http://www.appbrain.com/app/DroidEdit-free-code-editor/com.aor.droidedit):

[image: 920 Text Editor] [image: DroidEdit]
<sup>*920 Text Editor* and *DroidEdit* (Source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Both support at least syntax highlighting for several programming languages, and from the screenshot at least *DroidEdit* seems to be able to directly work with Dropbox (see the headline).

Comment: Is this answer up to date(Sep 12 '17)? or is there something better?

Comment: @kouty [920 Text Editor](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.jecelyin.editor/) can now be found on F-Droid (a more recent version [in my repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.jecelyin.editor.v2)). Apart from that: I don't use Dropbox, so I cannot really tell.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a third party file explorer, such as [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop))?

It allows you to select a way to open a file. If it finds an unknown extension, it asks you to open the file as text/audio/video.

Comment: ES File Explorer has been plagued with ads and privacy issues recently. Could you recommend another application that has this functionality?